Key Polynomials expansion in terms of Non-symmetric Hall-Littlewood functions
I know from Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials on Macdonald's book, that the following holds:
\begin{equation}
s_{\lambda} (x) = \sum_{T \in A} t^{charge(T)} HS_{cont(T)} (x;t)
\end{equation}
where A is the set of tableaux of shape $\lambda$ with weight (or content) equal to a partition, $cont(T)$ is the content of the tableaux $T$ and $HS_{\mu}$ is a Symmetric Hall-Littlewood Function.
This can also be written as
\begin{equation}
\label{Eq1}
s_{\lambda} (x) = \sum_{  \begin{smallmatrix}
T \\
sh(T) = \lambda \end{smallmatrix} } t^{charge(T)} H_{cont(T)} (x;t)
\end{equation}
where $sh(T)$ is the shape of $T$, $T$ is any tableaux and $H_{\eta}$ is a non-Symmetric Hall-Littlewood function. This is in virtue of the decomposition of $HS_{\lambda}$ as the s sum of all $H_{\eta}$ with $\eta = \sigma ( \lambda )$ for some $\sigma$ in the symmetric group.
In my research I have arrived to which seems to be an equality of the following kind
\begin{equation}
K_{\alpha} (x) =  \sum_{  \begin{smallmatrix}
T \\
Key_{+} (T) \leq K_{\alpha} \end{smallmatrix} } t^{charge_{\alpha}(T)} H_{cont(T)} (x;t)
\end{equation}
Where $K_{+} (T)$ is the right key tableuax of $T$, $K_{\alpha}$ is the right key tableaux associated to $\alpha$ and $charge_{\alpha}$ is a charge function which depends upon $\alpha$ and it's difficult to define so I will skip. Proving it has proven pretty hard, and I was unable to find any references that helps me.
I wanted to know if there is already an equality of the kind
\begin{equation}
K_{\alpha} (x) =  \sum_{  \begin{smallmatrix}
T \\
Key_{+} (T) \leq K_{\alpha}
\end{smallmatrix}
 } t^{ invariant (T) } H_{cont(T)} (x;t)
\end{equation}
where $invariant(T)$ is some invariant of $T$, proving that coincides with mine might be easier than proving the identity from scratch.
Edit:
After writing this post, I have realized that a consequence the second equation (I wasn't able to number them on this post), $charge_{ \alpha } (T) = charge (T')$ where $charge_{ \alpha }()$ is the charge that appears on the third equation and $charge ()$ is the classic Lascoux's and Schützenberger, and $T'$ is some tableaux of the same content and shape as $T$.
I will investigate this matter, but if there is any reference which might help me I would gladly welcome it.

This looks much more suited for MathOverflow.
